# How to access vendor extensions in api.mustache regarding imports when endpoints are regrouped by tags

Tags: tags, jax-rs, cxf, swagger-codegen, vendor-prefix

### Problem

The issue concerns swagger codegen and using multiple files to define specs.
I have two REST APIs with two different files specs1.yml and specs2.yml.

These specs have some models/schemas/*definitions* (I use swagger 2.0) in common.

I'd like to factorize these definitions in a core.yml file.
I can then reference these in specs1 and specs2.

The issue is that swagger codegen generates these models as part of specs1 and specs2. What I'd like is processing the core.yml file, generating classes in a *core* package, and then having the specs1/2 generated classes referencing the classes in the *core* package when it's a common one.

---

### Technical Stack

Maven / Java / JAXRS-CXF REST API

Maven 3.6.0

Java 1.8.0_201

swagger-jaxrs 1.5.16

CXF 3.1.14

swagger-codegen-maven-plugin 2.4.7

---

### Code Example

#### Swagger Specs YML

I have a tag named e.g. "Super Tag" in my swagger specs definition.
Multiple endpoints are regrouped under that tag. For the sake of a minimal PoC of my issue, let's go with one endpoint:
**specs1.yml**

```
swagger: "2.0"

tags:
  - name: "Super Tag"
    x-core-imports: [ErrorResponse] # Trying this at tag level
    x-imports: [ABody]              # Trying this at tag level

paths:

  /someEndpointPath:
    post:
      x-core-imports: [ErrorResponse] # --> import bla.core.api.models.ErrorResponse
      x-imports: [ABody]              # --> import bla.project.api.models.ABody
      tags:
        - "Super Tag"
      operationId: postToSomeEndpoint
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ABody' # This model is defined in this file
      responses:
        204:
          description: "Successful response"
        400:
          description: "Bad request error"
          schema:
            $ref: '../CORE.yml#/definitions/_ErrorResponse'
            # I'm importing this model definition from another file

definitions:
  ABody:
    type: object
    field:
      type: string
```

#### Swagger Codegen Debugging

I tried seeing where the vendor extensions would be added with regards to *imports: [{ "import": ... }]* (which is what's read from the api.mustache template, see below)

```
> java -DdebugSupportingFiles -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i specs.yml -l java > result.json
```

I can see
**result.json**

```
"apiInfo" : {
      "apis" : { [
            "parent" : [ ],
            "generatorClass" : "io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen",
            "supportJava6" : false,
            "sortParamsByRequiredFlag" : true,
            "groupId" : "io.swagger",
            "invokerPackage" : "io.swagger.client",
            "classVarName" : "superTag",
            "developerEmail" : "apiteam@swagger.io",
            "generateModelDocs" : true,
            "hasImport" : true,
            "generateModelTests" : true,
            "generateApiTests" : true,
            "classFilename" : "SuperTagApi",
            "usePlayWS" : false,
            "generateModels" : true,
            "serializableModel" : false,
            "playVersion" : "play25",
            "inputSpec" : "specs.yml",
            "artifactUrl" : "https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen",
            "developerOrganization" : "Swagger",
            "baseName" : "SuperTag",
            "package" : "io.swagger.client.api",
            "imports" : [ {
                  "import" : "io.swagger.client.model.ABody"
            }, {
                  "import" : "io.swagger.client.model.ErrorResponse"
            } ]
            ...
      ] }
}
```

#### Swagger Templates

We can see in the [**api.mustache** template](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/JavaJaxRS/cxf/api.mustache)

```
package {{package}};

{{#imports}}import {{import}};
{{/imports}}
```

I'm using the maven swagger codegen plugin with the following options:

```
<modelPackage>com.mysite.myproject.api.models</modelPackage>
<apiPackage>com.mysite.myproject.api</apiPackage>
```

So in my generated java class I will get:

**SuperTagApi.class**

```
package com.mysite.myproject.api;


import com.mysite.myproject.api.models.ErrorResponse;
import com.mysite.myproject.api.models.ABody;
```

What I'd like to do is have a means to tell swaggercodegen that I want one class imported as it is now, but the second imported from another package.

To do that, my idea was using vendor extensions (as you can see above) and manually list the classes that I want imported from a given package (that will actually be generated from the CORE.yml file) and the ones that are defined in my specs.yml where I want the original generated package name.

I tried adding *x-core-imports* vendor-extension to multiple different places trying to get access to them. None put them at the same level as the *imports: [{ "import": ... }]* section of the **result.json**... This is because different endpoints/methods are regrouped under the same file when their tag is identical.

I modified my api.mustache like so:

```
{{^vendorExtensions.x-imports}}
{{#imports}}import {{import}};
{{/imports}}
{{/vendorExtensions.x-imports}}

{{#vendorExtensions.x-imports}}
{{#vendorExtensions.x-core-imports}}
import com.mysite.core.api.models.{{.}};
{{/vendorExtensions.x-core-imports}}
import com.mysite.myproject.api.models.{{.}};
{{/vendorExtensions.x-imports}}
```

---

**Do you know at which level in the yml file I have to put my vendor extensions to be able to access them from api.mustache?** (Without modifying swagger codegen, just modifying templates and yml specs files)

Comment: You might have better luck asking this question in the Swagger Codegen repository at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues